# Eigenvector problem for a block toeplitz matrix

Tags: condensed-matter, ising-model

Consider a 2*2 block toeplitz real matrix A . The (i,j) block is given by

$$ \begin{matrix}
 -f_{i-j} & g_{i-j} \\
-g_{j-i} & f_{i-j}
\end{matrix}
$$
where i,j go from 1 to L.

f satisfies $f_{-a}=f_a$. Let $\vec{V}$ be an eigenvector of A, with eigenvalue $i\lambda$. (The eigenvalues have to be imaginary because A is antisymmetric). Now, define a vector $\vec{w}$ such that $w_i=V_{2i-1}$,  the toeplitz matrix $F_{i,j}=f_{i-j}$ and the Hankel matrix $H_{i,j}= g_{i+j-L-1}$

Evidently,
$(iF \pm H)\vec{w} = \mp i \lambda \vec{w}$

Can someone please help me prove this?